# What complexity mutiplication table code here have?

Tags: big-o

I think, below code have O(n^2 - n) complexity. but I had not seen that kinds of form of the big-o

```
def gugu(n:Int) = {
    for(i <- 2 to n) {
        for(k <- 1 to n) {
            println(s"$i * $k = " + (i * k))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: n^2, that's all that matters. You only care about the most significant contributor in O.

Comment: O(N^2) as Luaan said.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a total of n<sup>2</sup> - n entries will get printed out, and so your claim that the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup> - n) is technically correct. However, typically, when using big-O notation, you drop constant factors and lower-order terms to leave behind only the dominant growth term. Here, the n<sup>2</sup> term accounts for the overwhelming majority of the runtime of the function, so it would be better to say that the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>) as it more clearly communicates how the runtime scales.